# How can I create java array[][] using undefined number of arrays[]

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Just out of curiosity, based on that code is there a way to that instead of

```
int [][]d = { obj[0].ar , obj[1].ar , obj[2].ar };
```

can be written  under a `for` like this

```
for(int i=0;i<obj.ar.length;i++)
```

or to just combine all arrays of `obj[].ar` using `obj.length` in one 2 dimenstional array?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int nb = 3;
        arr[] obj = new arr[nb];
        
        for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
        {
            obj[i] = new arr(i+2);
        }
        
        int [][]d = { obj[0].ar , obj[1].ar , obj[2].ar };
        
        for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<d[i].length;j++)
                System.out.print(d[i][j]+"\t");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
class arr
{
    int []ar;
    arr(int nb)
    {
        ar = new int[nb];
        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
            ar[i]=i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays must always have a determined size upon creation.

Notice you are always setting `nb` in the calls to `new` arrays, or by using the `{}` instantiator which will count the number of objects statically.

What you are asking for is probably what `ArrayList` is meant to achieve. It will grow as you go, while having an array implementation behind the scenes. If the contents cannot fit in the array, a new - larger - array is created to fit them all. You won't notice this while using it though.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> obj = new ArrayList<>();

obj.add(new ArrayList<>());
obj.add(new ArrayList<>());
obj.add(new ArrayList<>());
// There are now three empty lists, in the main list.
```

Since java 9, you can use some extra helper methods:

```
List<List<Integer>> obj = List.of(
    List.of(1,2,3),
    List.of(2,3,4)
);
```

If you want, you can implement you own `ArrayList` class, it's not that hard!

Comment: "If you want, you can implement you own ArrayList class, it's not that hard!" It's not *too* difficult, but there has to be a very strong reason not to use the standard class.

Comment: Yes, I agree! This question looks like school stuff so I just wanted to point out that while there may be constraints like "don't use the built-ins", OP could get around that by implementing it themselves.